# Filter files in Windows Explorer Programmatically

Tags: windows, shell, explorer

Is it possible to **filter files in Windows Explorer programmatically**, say, building a shell extension? For example, right click on a folder, choose a custom menu "Filter by", and input "ABC*.pdf". Windows Explorer shows all pdf files starting with "ABC" only.

Possible? and how?

(BTW, I know how to add custom context menus for Windows Explorer through Shell extension.)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Everything is possible. All you need to know is right API

Comment: Isn't that what the search facility does in Windows Explorer?

Comment: T.S., "All you need to know is right API". Do you think I still want to waste my time and YOUR time to post my question here if I know the right API? Thank you for nothing.

Comment: rrirower, exactly, it is what the search does. One way to implement the "Filter" is to trigger the search on Windows Explorer pragmatically. Again, my question is how? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The explorer plugin [StExBar](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/StExBar.html) can do that: it adds a text box where you can enter a filter string and have the files filtered accordingly